# Jquery How to automatically assign an ascending integer for each row starting from 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now, when the rows no is entered and the button is clicked, respective no of rows will be added.

Now, i'd like to assign an ascending integer for each row starting from 1,
any idea guys?

```js
$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
  var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);

  if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
    alert('Please enter number of injection');
  } else {

    $tbody = $('table tbody');
    $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');

    additionalRows = new Array(numNewRows + 0).join($row[0].outerHTML);

    $tbody.append(additionalRows);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="insert-rows-amnt" name="insert-rows-amnt" value="<?php echo $tam ?>" />
<button id="add-row" type="button">Rows no</button>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="vaccineid[]"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width: 160px" name="vaccinename1[]"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This would be easier if you used an actual loop, instead of that array-join-voodoo ...

Comment: As CBroe stated. Just make a simple loop and create your elements dynamically instead of copying the first one. In that way you can assign the loop index to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the table body to include index on the table first column starting from 1

```js
$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
  var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);

  if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
    alert('Please enter number of injection');
  } else {

    $tbody = $('table tbody');
    $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');
    var lastRowIndex=($row.index()==-1? 0:$row.index()) +1 ;
    additionalRows = new Array(numNewRows);
    for(i=0;i<numNewRows;i++)
    {
    additionalRows[i]=` <tr>
    <td>${lastRowIndex}</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="vaccineid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width:160px"name="vaccinename1[]">       </td>
     </tr>`
      lastRowIndex=lastRowIndex+1;
    }
   
    $tbody.append(additionalRows.join());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="insert-rows-amnt" name="insert-rows-amnt" value="<?php echo $tam ?>" />
<button id="add-row" type="button">Rows no</button>
<table>
  <tbody>
 
</table>
```

Comment: Also, can the integer be shown within an input field so i can get that value and save to the database,thank

Answer (score 0):

Do with `while`. They will help to iterate the value

```js
$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
  var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);
var i =0;
  if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
    alert('Please enter number of injection');
  } else {

    $tbody = $('table tbody');
    $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');

while(i<numNewRows){
    additionalRows =$row[0].outerHTML
    $tbody.append(additionalRows);
    i++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="insert-rows-amnt" name="insert-rows-amnt" value="<?php echo $tam ?>" />
<button id="add-row" type="button">Rows no</button>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="vaccineid[]"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width: 160px" name="vaccinename1[]"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```